# I want to make a concealed "password" in Java

Tags: java, string, passwords

In Java I want to make such that when I'm typing a String as input the letters of the string do not appear on the console screen.  Is there anyway I can do that?

Answer (score 12):

Maybe Java 6's [Console.readPassword()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readPassword%28%29)?

Comment: I think the idea was to click on the link and then read the API for the class and method provided.